# Which would be better: use dispatch on many components or collect data and then dispatch it all?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have components

```
<Component>
   <ChildComponent1 />
   <ChildComponent2 />
   <ChildComponent3 />
   <ChildComponent4 />
   <ConfirmButton />
</Component>
```

Child components look like:

```
@connect(data => data)
class ChildComponent1 {

 change() {
  this.props.dispatch(action.someAction());//it dispatch to store
 }
 render() {
  return <select onChange={this.change}>{render select}</select>
 }
}
```

Child components value dispatches on each select value change, but i do nothing until I have collected data from all child components.
Maybe it would be better dispatch all data after collecting it.

```
render(
     return  <Component>
                <ChildComponent1 onChange={(data) => this.setState({data})} /> //uses arrow function in this place it is bad, but it is example 
                <ChildComponent2 onChange={(data1) => this.setState({data1})}  />
                <ChildComponent3 onChange={(data2) => this.setState({data2})}  />
                <ChildComponent4 onChange={(data3) => this.setState({data3})}  />
                <ConfirmButton onApply={() => this.props.dispatch(this.getState())} />
            </Component>
)
```

What is better approach ?

Comment: how do you determine if you have collected data from all child components? If it is when a button is clicked, then dispatch on that button click. If it is when users stop selecting, then use a setTimeout to dispatch.

Comment: It is simple example, i have validation for user input.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it, I'm assuming you're using babel to traspile JS, and that your actions are defined in './redux/actions'.
You're probably using "[babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-decorators/)", but to run this code you need to add "[transform-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)"

```
import actions from './redux/actions';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  reducer: state.reducer,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  onChangeAction: actions.someAction,
};

@connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
class ChildComponent1 {

  change = () => {
    this.props.onChangeAction();//it dispatches to store
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <select onChange={this.change}>{render select}</select>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, what do ChildComponentX do? Which kind of data does it handle?

Comment: ChildComponentX it is select and multiselect. I dispatch selected ids, when applies button I need change another component which depend from this data.